# .NET Ajax Call gives 401

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have this WebMethod that returns some schedule hours from a webservice and i'm calling it with Jquery Ajax but it gives me a 401 (Unauthorized)

```
responseText: "{"Message":"Failed to Authenticate","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"
```

I have already tried almost everything here and on Google but i couldn't find the problem with mine.

Here is my Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: CaminhoSite() + 'QueroDesconto.aspx/BuscaHorarios',
    data: JSON.stringify({ pUnidadeCE: codigoEmitente, data: dataFinal }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg)
    {
        if( msg.d != "")
        {
            var horarios = $.parseJSON( msg.d );
            montaHorariosAgenda(horarios);
        }
        else
        {
            montaHorariosAgenda("");
        }
        },
        error: function (e)
        {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Here is my method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string BuscaHorarios(int pUnidadeCE, string data)
{
    var objAgendamento = new Agendamento { UnidadeCE = pUnidadeCE };

    if (!objAgendamento.BuscarHorariosAgendamento(objAgendamento, data)) return "";

    var objJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objAgendamento.lstHorarios);

    return objJson;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: What authentication type you using in your service?

Comment: @TasosK. If i use GET do i have to change something ?

Comment: @Vladimirs The autentication is made on the connection with the service but this is not the problem because other calls work perfectly

Comment: I don't think that you need to change something else, just `POST` to `GET`.

Comment: @TasosK. It didn't work, now i have a 500 error cause i need the parameters (pUnidadeCE and data) and also because of the url

Comment: In that case I would try put the variables in the query string. But I would like to ask why are you using jQuery when you could call `PageMethods.BuscaHorarios(codigoEmitente, dataFinal, function(data) { /* success */ }, function() { /* error*/ });`

Comment: @TasosK. I was using it 'cause i don't know a lot about .NET and didn't know this method.

It worked like a charm, you just saved my day ! Post it as an answer please ?

Comment: I posted it as an answer, glad I helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call this method without using jQuery and sticking with the way ASP.NET provides.

```
function success(data) {
    // handle data accordingly
}    

function error() {
    // an exception occurred when the method executed
}    

PageMethods.BuscaHorarios(codigoEmitente, dataFinal, success, error);
```

[Here](http://codingstill.com/2012/02/asp-net-and-ajax-all-about-update-panels-web-methods-page-methods-and-jquery/) is a relevant article I wrote a while ago describing how one can use PageMethods and WebMethods in ASP.NET.

Also you can take a look in the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which is available in MVC and also in Web Forms. Web API works very well with jQuery.